# Why I get this error in CXF

Tags: java, web-services, cxf

I want to make dynamic web service invoker in JSF with CXF. But when I load this simple code I get error.
The code:

```
JaxWsDynamicClientFactory dcf = JaxWsDynamicClientFactory.newInstance();
Client client = dcf.createClient("http://ws.strikeiron.com/IPLookup2?wsdl");
```

The error:

No Factories configured for this Application. This happens if the faces-initialization does not work at all - make sure that you properly include all configuration settings necessary for a basic faces application and that all the necessary libs are included. Also check the logging output of your web application and your container for any exceptions! If you did that and find nothing, the mistake might be due to the fact that you use some special web-containers which do not support registering context-listeners via TLD files and a context listener is not setup in your web.xml. A typical config looks like this;  org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener

Caused by:
java.lang.IllegalStateException - No Factories configured for this Application. This happens if the faces-initialization does not work at all - make sure that you properly include all configuration settings necessary for a basic faces application and that all the necessary libs are included. Also check the logging output of your web application and your container for any exceptions! If you did that and find nothing, the mistake might be due to the fact that you use some special web-containers which do not support registering context-listeners via TLD files and a context listener is not setup in your web.xml. A typical config looks like this;  org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener

Any Idea how to solve the problem?

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>ServiceInvoker</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <description>
    This parameter tells MyFaces if javascript code should be allowed in
    the rendered HTML output.
    If javascript is allowed, command_link anchors will have javascript code
    that submits the corresponding form.
    If javascript is not allowed, the state saving info and nested parameters
    will be added as url parameters.
    Default is 'true'</description>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.ALLOW_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <description>
    If true, rendered HTML code will be formatted, so that it is 'human-readable'
    i.e. additional line separators and whitespace will be written, that do not
    influence the HTML code.
    Default is 'true'</description>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.PRETTY_HTML</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.DETECT_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <description>
    If true, a javascript function will be rendered that is able to restore the
    former vertical scroll on every request. Convenient feature if you have pages
    with long lists and you do not want the browser page to always jump to the top
    if you trigger a link or button action that stays on the same page.
    Default is 'false'
</description>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.AUTO_SCROLL</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
</web-app>
```

**faces-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<faces-config
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_1_2.xsd"
    version="1.2">
    <managed-bean>
        <description>Bean used for invoking services</description>
        <managed-bean-name>invoker</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>org.cot.invoker.Invoker</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>

</faces-config>
```

This is what I get in the console in Eclipse:

22.3.2010 15:00:11 org.apache.cxf.endpoint.dynamic.DynamicClientFactory outputDebug
INFO: Created classes: com.strikeiron.ws.GetRemainingHits, com.strikeiron.ws.GetRemainingHitsResponse, com.strikeiron.ws.LicenseInfo, com.strikeiron.ws.ObjectFactory, com.strikeiron.ws.RegisteredUser, com.strikeiron.ws.SubscriptionInfo, com.strikeiron.ws.UnregisteredUser, com.strikeiron.ArrayOfMethodStatusRecord, com.strikeiron.ArrayOfSIWsStatus, com.strikeiron.ArrayOfServiceInfoRecord, com.strikeiron.ArrayOfString, com.strikeiron.ArrayOfString1, com.strikeiron.DNSInfo, com.strikeiron.DNSLookup, com.strikeiron.DNSLookupResponse, com.strikeiron.GetServiceInfo, com.strikeiron.GetServiceInfoResponse, com.strikeiron.GetStatusCodes, com.strikeiron.GetStatusCodesForMethod, com.strikeiron.GetStatusCodesForMethodResponse, com.strikeiron.GetStatusCodesResponse, com.strikeiron.MethodStatusRecord, com.strikeiron.ObjectFactory, com.strikeiron.SIWsOutputOfDNSInfo, com.strikeiron.SIWsOutputOfMethodStatusRecord, com.strikeiron.SIWsOutputOfSIWsResultArrayOfMethodStatusRecord, com.strikeiron.SIWsOutputOfSIWsResultArrayOfServiceInfoRecord, com.strikeiron.SIWsResultArrayOfMethodStatusRecord, com.strikeiron.SIWsResultArrayOfSIWsStatus, com.strikeiron.SIWsResultArrayOfServiceInfoRecord, com.strikeiron.SIWsStatus, com.strikeiron.ServiceInfoRecord
je slo
22.3.2010 15:00:13 javax.faces.webapp._ErrorPageWriter handleThrowable
SEVERE: An exception occurred
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Factories configured for this Application. This happens if the faces-initialization does not work at all - make sure that you properly include all configuration settings necessary for a basic faces application and that all the necessary libs are included. Also check the logging output of your web application and your container for any exceptions!
If you did that and find nothing, the mistake might be due to the fact that you use some special web-containers which do not support registering context-listeners via TLD files and a context listener is not setup in your web.xml.
A typical config looks like this;

  org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener

```
at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:106)
at org.apache.myfaces.application.jsp.JspViewHandlerImpl.renderView(JspViewHandlerImpl.java:356)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:41)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:140)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:155)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

when I click on:

```
<h:commandLink value="Invoke me!" actionListener="#{invoker.doInvoke}"></h:commandLink>
```

Comment: show us the `faces-config.xml` and `web.xml`

Comment: I add also faces-config.xml and web.xml. Hm... Im already 2 days trying  to solve this problem

Comment: is there any other exceptions/errors in the log files? Like `NoClassDefFound`, for example

Comment: Ill paste in the question what I get in the console in eclipse when I click on the link which activate action in the ManagedBean

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid some error like "No Factories configured for this Application" using a CXF Dynamic Client and JSF, you must to do something like this:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
JaxWsDynamicClientFactory dcf = JaxWsDynamicClientFactory.newInstance();
Client client = dcf.createClient("http://ws.strikeiron.com/IPLookup2?wsdl");
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(classLoader);
```

Answer (score 0):

The errors you quote have nothing to do with CXF, but rather with org.apache.myfaces.

If all that came back from the server, then you have the wrong URL for the ?wsdl. Does browsing that URL produce the WSDL file in an ordinary browser?

You can probably get better debugging assistance on this at the CXF user mailing list. This isn't so much a question as a diagnostic issue that will take a lot of back and forth.

Comment: The wsdl? url is ok. In ordinary browser I see the WSDL doc.
Probably the problem is in the myFaces. But where.... I dont have idea.